# how to set path in MSI installer?

Tags: c#, .net, installation, windows-installer

I am using VS2008 setup project to build our msi installer. I have moved some dll files from the default location (root folder of the installation) to a custom bin directory. I think I need to set path in somewhere (registry?) to tell the application the new loation of those dll files. How to do this? thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just open up the .vdproj file in notepad and search for the dll files you moved. Then adjust the dll path (usually called SourcePath). You should not edit anything in the Registry! Only edit this file.

Comment: I modified that SoucePath to the new "bin\\mydll.dll" or ".\\bin\\mydll.dll" location, but still got the same exception which complain cannot find that file.

Comment: remember, the path in SourcePath is the relative path to the assembly (relative from the vdproj file). Your path is likely not "bin\my.dll", because you probably do not have dlls in your setup directory. In my project it look like this: "SourcePath" = "8:..\\..\\MyDlls\\My.dll". Verify that the path is correct and it should work.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clean. my exception is not at compile time, it is at run time, after the installation. I tried your way, the relative path from the vdproj file. the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If these are references in your project, I would remove the references and add them back using the Browse tab of the Add Reference dialog.